# Saving and restoring a UIWebView browsing session

Tags: iphone, ios, browser, uiwebview, webkit

With UIWebView class, is it possible to save a browsing session when the app's goes into background and then fully restore it when the app is activated or relaunched afresh? According to the documentation, UIWebView class does conform to the NSCoding protocol, but will archiving an instance of UIWebView class also preserve the cookies **and** the JavaScript state of the page (and maybe HTML5 local storage too) so that the page restores with identically the same look and with exact same functionality? My app views pages with heavy and scattered graphics and JavaScript which loads for way too long over cellular so saving browsing sessions would be a really, really nice improvement to have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably not. Even Safari doesn't do this.

All UIView classes conform to NSCoding in order to support unarchiving from nib files, to set up a user interface. This is a special case and not a general purpose archive/unarchive mechanism that exists for other classes.

There are probably some things you could do:

- Save and restore scroll position.
- Aggressively cache data; look at the docs for the URL loading system, this is what UIWebView uses. It does some caching by default but I believe you can tune it to do more.
- Save and restore session cookies, which would normally be discarded (see HTTPCookieStorage).